# Matching Perforce Moves done on Linux to Windows

Tags: linux, windows, perforce, p4v

I have set up a shared workspace using the AltRoots parameter so that I can run my code on a Linux Machine and develop on my Windows Machine (personal preference). I have done some "`p4 move`"'s on files in Linux. However, these moves do not get updated on my Windows workspace. The pending Windows changelist has the "move" changes, but then when I try to submit on Windows (along with other edits) P4V is complaining that those moved files do not exist.

How can I force a hard sync between my workspace areas? Or have Windows actually update when I do a "`P4 move`" on Linux?

Thanks!

Comment: So you're running a move and submitting on Linux, then trying to sync the changes on Windows?  You'll need to run 'sync -f' on those files on Windows if you're sharing a workspace.

Comment: What do you mean by "not get updated on my Windows workspace"?  If you're truly sharing a workspace, it'd be the same workspace.  Are you sharing a Perforce workspace without sharing the underlying files, or are you sharing your source tree via Samba or something?

Comment: FWIW, I just tried moving a file on Linux and submitting on Windows using a shared Perforce client with a source tree shared over Samba, and I had no issue.

Answer (score 0):

To have a "shared workspace" between two machines the actual workspace filesystem needs to be shared (e.g. via Samba).

Perforce itself does not replicate local filesystem changes between two hosts sharing a single client spec; as far as Perforce is concerned everything is synced via the depot (meaning you need to use two client specs and submit [or shelve] changes from one before syncing them to the other).

For the workflow you describe, using [Samba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samba_(software)) sounds like the way to go.  Since your development environment is on Windows I'd further recommend that you use the "win" LineEnd setting (hopefully your Linux tools know how to speak CRLF -- if not I might suggested a workflow based around shelving instead, since that'll let Perforce do the LineEnd translation for you).